# Are extended attributes name and value guaranteed to be UTF-8 encoded

Tags: linux, unix, xattr

I am trying to implement Rusty wrappers for those extended attributes syscalls, if they are guaranteed to be UTF-8 encoded, then I can use the type `String`, or I have to use `OsString`.

I googled a lot, but only found these two pages:

- [freedesktop: CommonExtendedAttributes](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/CommonExtendedAttributes/) says that:
  Attribute strings should be in UTF-8 encoding.
- [macOS man page for `setxattr(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setxattr.2.html) says that: The extended attribute names are simple NULL-terminated UTF-8 strings

  > Seems that this tells us the `name` is guaranteed to be UTF-8 encoded on macOS,

I would like to know information on as many platforms as possible since I try to cover them all in my implementation.

Comment: What problem would it cause if some Windows implementation uses a code page? It's still a null-terminated string.

Comment: @stark  Emma, I am sorry, I don't quite understand, what is a `code page`? And I didn't mention windows in my question at all.

Comment: The point is you have a series of non-zero bytes, terminated by a 0.  What difference does it make what the encoding is?  That just affects how they are displayed, not how the program handles them.

Comment: @stark I totally understand what you mean now. But that is the situation in C.  Not in Rust, I am adding Rust bindings for those C syscalls.

Comment: @stark I am sorry, why did you tag this question `rust`? yes, I am adding bindings in rust, but the core of this question has nothing to do with rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in Linux they are absolutely not guaranteed to be in UTF-8. Attribute values are not even guaranteed to be strings at all. They are just arrays of bytes with no constraints on them.

```
int setxattr(const char *path, const char *name,
             const void *value, size_t size, int flags);
```

`const void *value, size_t size` is not a good way to pass a string to a function. `const char* name` is, and attribute names are indeed strings, but they are null-terminated *byte* strings.

Freedesktop recommendations are just that, recommendations. They don't prevent anyone from creating any attribute they want.

Comment: Makes sense, `const void *, size_t` is definitely not something prepared for string. Would you like to tell me the situation of [`sethostname(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html), it has the signature of `const char *name, size_t len`, is `hostname` guaranteed to be a string?

Comment: `sethostname` is a pretty bad interface. Different versions of it do not agree whether the argument must be null-terminated or not, but at least they all agree that it should be a string of some sort. I have no idea why they included the size there. Perhaps for backwards compatibility with something arcane and long obsolete. `setxattr` is not like that. The Linux manual is pretty clear about `value` being arbitrary data, not necessarily a string. I just didn't want to quote a long winded passage. Read it, especially the section on value encoding in getfattr(1).